# Android - Prevent click to perform an update during an update in App Widget

Tags: java, android, service, widget

I have a home screen widget and I have some trouble with it. I update my widget on click on the widget. A service starts, sets a message in the widget (Loading...) and updates the widget. It works correctly but if I click several times on the widget, the widget keeps in memory that I have clicked several times and it updates it several times when the previous click was treated.

Here is a sketch to really understand how it works (because my english is not as good as I wish): http://hpics.li/f3bcbaa

Thank you in advance for your help. If you need some code to understand what I would like to have, just ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like that?

```
boolean updateIsRunning = false;

if (!updateIsRunning)
{
    updateIsRunning = true;
    //perform your update
    updateIsRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: I tried this before you answer and it doesn't work. The widget updates again when the previous update is finished

Comment: so what about stocking lastUpdateDate and comparingto it, or you'll have to make the all update process async

Comment: Thanks Anthony! I stocked the timestamp before operation in SharedPreferences and when the user clicks on the widget it will check if 5 seconds have passed first. Merci beaucoup !